# How to filter out child element events in a event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, event-delegation

I have bootstrap button-group. Also, a jQuery based event handler (uses event delegation) that sets/unsets the bootstrap .active class on the appropriate .btn based on click event.

The problem happens when my buttons have html elements inside it. When you click on the child element of a button, the .active class is set on the .btn's child elements.

How do I only receive events for the precise elements I am interested in ?

http://jsfiddle.net/0nc3wjq4/
To reproduce the problem, please click on one of the numbers in a button and then click on another number in a different button.

```
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified pipeline" role="group">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">
        <h3 class="text-center">767</h3>
        <p class="text-muted text-center">Stage1</p>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Event Handler

```
$( ".btn-group" ).on( "click", ".btn", function( e ) {
    $(this).siblings(".active").removeClass('active'); // previous
    $(e.target).addClass('active'); // current
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `$(e.target)` with `$(this)`

`e.target` is showing as the `h3`/`p` and not the `button`

`e.target` is the element that triggered the event, ie - the `h3` you clicked which propagated the event on to the `a.btn`. That then got caught by your event handler.

`this` is the element which triggered the handler.

Comment: Great thanks. Would be great if could you also point to documentation or explain the difference between $(this) and e.target  @bg101

Comment: It's in the [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation: _Note that `this` may not be equal to `event.target` if the event has bubbled from a descendant element._

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/0nc3wjq4/1/)***

You were looking for return false. This will stop propagation (which is different than prevent default), and also prevent the default click action. In addition, you may take advantage of chaining here to do this in two lines.

```
$('.btn').on('click',function(){   
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings(".active").removeClass('active');
    return false;
});
```